# Using the master .h / .m for a secondary Popup view - Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

So I have a "main" View linked with my main .h/.m ViewController files.

In a process of the application, a second View is called that overlays part of my main View in a "popup" style.

I'm wondering if it's a good idea to use the original main ViewController .h/.m files for both the main View, and the second View? If not, I'm genuinely interested in why that is not to be considered a good idea. If this is in-fact a standard practice, what is the cleanest way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

It's typically good practice for your view controller to "control" what comes on and off the displayed view its responsible for.  If you are just presenting something very simple, it would be fine leaving it (the code) in your view controller - an example of this might be a background view with a different color.

If however, your view has many responsibilities, such as responding to touch events, you may want to create a subclass of UIView and put your code in that file.  Then back in your original view controller, you would simply import that subclass and instantiate the view and present it (add subview) when needed.

Using a common pattern like delegation, your subclassed UIView would control it's own logic and perhaps via delegation, send messages back to the view controller when needed for items like dismiss, or save or any number of functions it might do.  A common example of this is UITableView.

hope that helps